# Merge 2 variables into 1?

Tags: r, merge

Suppose my original data looks something like this

```
df <- data.frame(id = 1:10,
                 V = LETTERS[1:10],
                 Treatment1 = c(rep(1,3), rep(0,7)),
                 Treatment2 = c(rep(0,3), rep(1,3), rep(0,4)))
```

I would like to merge `Treatment1` and `Treatment2` into a new variable that takes 1 of 3 values: `Treatment1`, `Treatment2`, `Control`. That is I would like to end up with this data frame:

```
df2 <- data.frame(id = 1:10,
                  V = LETTERS[1:10],
                  Treatment = c(rep("Treatment1",3), 
                                rep("Treatment2",3),
                                rep("Control",4)))
```

Right now I'm doing it with this code:

```
library(dplyr)
df$Treatment <- ifelse(test = df$Treatment1==1, yes = "Treatment1", 
                       no = ifelse(test = df$Treatment2==1, 
                                   yes = "Treatment2", no = "Control"))

df2 <- df %>% select(-Treatment1, -Treatment2)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: As far as I can see this question is entirely unrelated to tidyr and dplyr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it that ends up being reasonably readable and extendable is to create a lookup table and merge it with your existing data as follows:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Treatment1 = c(1,0,0),
                  Treatment2 = c(0,1,0),
                  Treatment = c("Control", "Treatment1", "Treatment2"));
merge(df, df2, all.x=TRUE)  #Setting all.x ensures rows of df aren't dropped if there isn't a match

 #      Treatment1 Treatment2 id V  Treatment
 #   1           0          0  7 G Treatment2
 #   2           0          0  8 H Treatment2
 #   3           0          0  9 I Treatment2
 #   4           0          0 10 J Treatment2
 #   5           0          1  4 D Treatment1
 #   6           0          1  5 E Treatment1
 #   7           0          1  6 F Treatment1
 #   8           1          0  1 A    Control
 #   9           1          0  2 B    Control
 #   10          1          0  3 C    Control
```

Answer (score 2):

We can do this without any `ifelse`

```
df$Treatment <- with(df, c("Control", "Treatment1", "Treatment2")[(Treatment1 +
                                2*Treatment2)+1])
df$Treatment
#[1] "Treatment1" "Treatment1" "Treatment1" "Treatment2" "Treatment2" 
#[6] "Treatment2" "Control"    "Control"    "Control"    "Control"
```

---

Or another option is with `pmax`

```
c("Control", "Treatment1", "Treatment2")[do.call(pmax, df[3:4]*col(df[3:4]))+1]
#[1] "Treatment1" "Treatment1" "Treatment1" "Treatment2" "Treatment2" 
#[6] "Treatment2" "Control"    "Control"    "Control"    "Control"
```

---

If this needs to be compared with 'df2', `paste` the 3rd and 4th columns together from 'df', set the names of the `unique` elements of 'Treatment' in 'df2' with the unique elements from 'v1' (in the example it is in the same order) use that to replace the values.

```
v1 <- do.call(paste0, df[3:4])
unname(setNames(as.character(unique(df2$Treatment)), c("10", "01", "00"))[v1])
#[1] "Treatment1" "Treatment1" "Treatment1" "Treatment2" "Treatment2" 
#[6] "Treatment2" "Control"    "Control"    "Control"    "Control"
```

NOTE: All these methods used no package and should be efficient

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr::case_when` is a good alternative to nested `ifelse`s:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(Treatment = case_when(.$Treatment1 == 1 ~ 'Treatment1', 
                                    .$Treatment2 == 1 ~ 'Treatment2', 
                                    TRUE ~ 'Control')) %>% 
    select(-Treatment1, -Treatment2)
    ##    id V  Treatment
    ## 1   1 A Treatment1
    ## 2   2 B Treatment1
    ## 3   3 C Treatment1
    ## 4   4 D Treatment2
    ## 5   5 E Treatment2
    ## 6   6 F Treatment2
    ## 7   7 G    Control
    ## 8   8 H    Control
    ## 9   9 I    Control
    ## 10 10 J    Control
```

As it's still new and somewhat experimental, `case_when` requires `$` notation in `mutate` [for now](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/06/27/dplyr-0-5-0/), but [it looks like that will change](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1719) before too long.